# Zero-init a data block in BSS on ARM

Tags: assembly, windows-phone-8, arm

Microsoft ARM assembler, targeting Windows Phone. I would like to create a long (~6KB), zero-inited data block in the BSS section. Please, what's a good syntax for that? The % directive does not zero-init, does it? Is the BSS section zero-inited by default, by any chance?

Comment: Microsoft say that they follow RealView's syntax in most cases, so you should be able to use [`{label} FILL expr{,value{,valuesize}}`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/index.html). From the reference: _"value must be 0 in a NOINIT area."_. That suggests to me that it will be zero-initied.

Comment: Right. Make an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916385.aspx) on Microsoft's ARM assembler directives states that *"For the most part, the Microsoft ARM assembler uses the ARM assembly language, which is documented in Chapter 7 of the ARM assembler tools guide. "*.

[Section 7.3.4](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Babchded.html) of said guide covers the `FILL` and `SPACE` directives, and has this to say about `FILL`:

> {label} FILL expr{,value{,valuesize}}`
>
> value
>      evaluates to the value to fill the reserved bytes with. value is optional and if omitted, it is 0. **value
>      must be 0 in a NOINIT area**.

This implies that the memory block will be zero-initialized if it's in a NOINIT area (which `.bss` should be).